# Selecionar categoria e subcategoria dentro da mesma tabela

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho a tabela chamada `modulos` e dentro dela eu inclui idModulo, idModuloBase, modulo, pasta e datacriacao

Quando o idModuloBase for 0, é a categoria, se estiver > 0, é o modulo preenchido.
Preciso fazer um SQL que liste as categorias e subcategorias dentro de cada um...

[image: Este seria o baco de dados]
[image: E esta é a lista que preciso ter]

Alguém consegue me sugerir algum SQL que faça isso? Grato.

Comment: Você só tem 2 níveis de categorias, ou isso é indeterminado?

Comment: São apenas dois níveis: 0 - categoria principal - >0 é a categoria que está preenchida... Pra não precisar fazer duas tabelas separadas de categoria e subcategoria...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como são apenas dois níveis, basta um `JOIN` da tabela com ela mesma (um *self join*):

```
SELECT
   modulo.*, 
   principal.idModulo AS idModuloBase,
   principal.modulo AS moduloBase,
   principal.pasta AS pastaBase
FROM modulos AS modulo
INNER JOIN modulos AS principal
ON principal.idModulo = modulo.idModuloBase
```

Comment: Agradeço, deu certinho! :)

Answer (score 1):

Não vejo uma *query* que possa solucionar bem o problema, por isso sugiro faze-lo no PHP.

```
<?php

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM modulos WHERE idMoludoBase = 0";
  // Execute sua query

  $modulos = Array();
  while ($row = $res->fetch()) {

     $sql = "SELECT * FROM modulos WHERE idMoludoBase = {$row['idModulo']}";
     // Execute sua query

     // Se ten submodulos
     if ($sres){
        // Adicione todos na chave submodulos
        $row['submodulos'] = $sres->fetchAll();
     }

     // Adicona a linha ao array de modulos
     $modulos[] = $row;
  }
```

<sub>O código acime é "apenas um algorítimo", deve ser adaptado de acordo com seu *drive* de *database*.</sub>

Saída da variável `$modulos`:

```
  $modulos => Array(
     [
        idModulo      => 1
        idModuloBase  => 0 
        modulo        => Cadastros
        ...
        submodulos    => Array(
           [
              idModulo       => 2
              idModuloBase   => 1
              modulo         => Cedentes
              ...
           ],
           [ ... ]
        )
     ], 
     [ ... ]
  )
```